# Could not retrieve image from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, microsoft-teams

I have a .NET application which has to send adaptive card to the end users through MS Teams. The adaptive card contains an image. The image has to be loaded from an Azure Blob Container in an Azure Storage Account.

But the image is not getting rendered in adaptive card because the Network Settings of Storage account has been already set as to allow traffic from only "Selected Networks". If I have updated the settings to allow "All Networks", the image is getting rendered.

Kindly suggest how to render the image in the adaptive card with the Network Settings of Storage account being set as to allow traffic from only "Selected Networks".

Comment: You can always get the bas64 string of the image and load that directly into the card.  That's how I used to approach it at times because it then meant no reliance on potentially private endpoints and firewalls, etc. at the end user point.

Answer (score 0):

Any file referenced in Teams (e.g. in Adaptive Cards or similar) needs to be publicly / anonymously Internet accessible, so that Teams can fetch and cache a copy on your behalf. You'd need to make the image available from All Networks, or base64 encode as the commenter suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is necesary a configuration with a public level to the container.

My console is in Spanish, sorry, but In this image you can see the options to configure with public level

[image]